# canplaythrough firing intermitently in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, jplayer

I'm trying to preload audio files for a game. I'm using Jplayer. I have an overlay that gets removed once all audio has been preloaded. In Firefox, sometimes canplaythrough gets fired, sometimes not. I have five audio files, sometimes I get three canplaythrough events, sometimes four, not often do I get all of them. If I log which ones work, the event isn't always fired, or not, on the same audio files.

I've tried to break the code as much as possible. Here I am adding a new Jplayer instance for each audio file, I still get the same problem.

{

```
        for(var i = 0; i < _timeOutAudioFilesToLoad; i++){
            c = i + 1;
            var elid = "timeOutAudio"+c;
            var elt = '<div id="'+elid+'" class="audioPlayer audio-player" data-audio-file="/themes/foo/sounds/time'+c+'.mp3"></div>';  
            $("#jPlayers").append(elt);
            $("#"+elid).jPlayer( {
                swfPath: "/themes/foo/js/libs/jPlayer250/Jplayer.swf"
            });     
        }
```

}

{

```
        $(".audioPlayer").each(function(){
            var audioFile = $(this).attr("data-audio-file");
            $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.canplaythrough, function(event) { 
                _loadWatcher();
            });
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: audioFile});
        })
```

}

The _loadWatcher() function gets called by some, but not others.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug with a workaround? I've tried the Jplayer Google Group, but for some reason, they're taking days and days to mod questions.

Thanks

Comment: I'm also suffering this issue in Chrome. Did you ever find what the cause was and a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I was binding the event before instantiating jPlayer on the element. I didn't realise that jplayer was actually waiting for a custom event - not the standard HTML5 event - so I thought binding anywhere would be OK. You live and learn. So switching the order of the last two lines in the for loop fixed the problem.